# php - Plugin/theme relative PATH/URI

Tags: php, paths, plugins-url

I would like to get relative path from a php file without knowing the absolute path.
I have succeeded to do it but for a reason which I don't know, on some servers (in rare case) it doesn't work when I enqueue css/js. Slashes are missing...

Here the code:

```
define('PATH', trailingslashit(str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__))));
define('URI', site_url(str_replace(trailingslashit(str_replace('\\', '/',ABSPATH)), '', PATH)))
```

What did I miss? Does it come from the server or the code itself?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do it, you can never know if the plugins directory is even "below" ABSPATH, and you can not know the URL out of the directory path https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories.

Just use the core api of plugins_utl etc, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there isn't any native Wordpress function that will match my needs. In fact, the file will not be loaded directly from the root folder. I build a metabox framework which can be included in any plugin or theme. So, it must automatically fetch the right path without knowing if its a theme/plugin and where is the framework folder in the theme/plugin. The aim is to use url/path to enqueue/require/include.

Comment: and that is exactly why you should use the core api instead of reinventing things, and if there is something that cab bot be done with core api then it is very likely it is not worth being done at this point in time for your specific use case.

Comment: And do you have an example of how to make it work? Because I don't know how to use a native Wordpress function to handle what I want to do. It seems that all frameworks are using php functions and not Wordpress functions because it seems not possible... If have a working example, I will be great! With `plugin_dir_url` it's not working, still the same issue on some server...

Comment: it sounds like what you want to do is fixed easily but having some initialization api that will let your code know where it is installed.

Comment: Of course, but I don't want to defined a constant before, to run correctly the framework. Eventually, if I can detect if the current file is from a plugin or a theme then i could use `plugin_dir_url` and `plugin_dir_path`...

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_url_from_path ($path) {

    // clean paths
    $dir_path = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path ) ); // file or directory
    $site_dir = trailingslashit( str_replace( '\\', '/', ABSPATH ) ); // path set in wp-config

    // remove server directory from path
    $file_rel = str_replace( $site_dir, '', $dir_path );

    // convert relative url to absolute url
    $dir_rel_url = site_url ($file_rel, 'http' );

    // return
    return $dir_rel_url;    
}

// __FILE__ and __DIR__ are referencing the php calling these functions

echo get_url_from_path (__FILE__);

echo trailingslashit( get_url_from_path (__DIR__) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you did near the same thing. it doesn't solve the issue...

Comment: Maybe show a few examples of files and how you expect the url to end up.  It would be pretty easy to find a solution with more information. Also, maybe where you are expecting to call this function because __FILE__ and __DIR__ will change.

Comment: I use it, for example, with `wp_enqueue_style('css', URI .'assets/css/file.css');`. In rare case, on some server, the slashes are completely missing and then the file is not enqueued because the url became false.

Comment: trailingslashit ( URI ) will make sure there is always a '/' at the end. But if your __FILE__ and __DIR__ are missing slashes, that has nothing to do with WordPress. Actually, your whole question really isn't WordPress related. What are you getting on these bad servers from __FILE__? And is there something in $_SERVER or $_REQUEST that shows the correct path?

Comment: It was mentionned in my question...